# Python inheritance - how to inherit class function?

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I'm new with python and having some trouble regarding inheritance.

i have this class:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        pass     
    def func1(self):
        op1()
        op2()
    def func2(self):
        pass
```

I'm using another class that is overriding it :

```
class B(A):
    def func2(self):
        # do something
```

the problem is that I want to get `func1` with all its operations and add for example `op3()`
so that when using this class I will have the option to use `op1`, `op2` or `op3`.

I've tried using:

```
def func1(self):
    op3()
```

but it just gave me the option of `op3` without `op1` and `op2`.

I saw that there is "super" option but I'm not sure I understand how to use it.

Comment: Also, you need to have `__init__`, not `_init_`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can call the super-class implementation in `func1`:

```
class B(A):
    def func1(self):
        super(B, self).func1()
        op3()
```

Here `super(B, self).func1` will search the class hierarchy in MRO (method resolution order), from class `B` onwards for the next `func1()` method, bind it to `self` and let you call it.

This will invoke the original `func1()` first, executing `op1()` and `op2()`, and your overridden version can then add new operations to follow.

You could also call `op3()` *first*, then invoke the base implementation.

You can also look up the parent method directly on class `A`, but that method will then be unbound. Pass in `self` explicitly:

```
class B(A):
    def func1(self):
        A.func1(self)
        op3()
```

This bypasses searching the class inheritance hierarchy making your class less flexible.

See [Raymond Hettinger's blog post on `super()`](http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/) for some excellent practical advice on when to use `super()`.

Comment: Or also `A.func1(self)`, no?

Comment: @qwertynl: Yes, but that'd be a non-cooperative invocation. Using `super()` you can add another version of `func1()` into the mix too.

Comment: @qwertynl In such an easy case, yes. But with a `class B(A,C,F,G):`, these parent classes having similiar dependencies, it gets more complicated.

Comment: so is there a difference between A.func1(self) and super(B,self)?

Comment: @user1386966: Not until you start mixing in more base classes, or create more complicated structures. The thing is, production code has this habit of evolving and becoming more complex over time.

Comment: Note that using `super()` requires the methods to be written in a specific style.  I generally recommend using `BaseClass.method(...)` unless you really know what you are doing.  I've seen a lot of broken code that resulted from using `super()` in the wrong way, in particular when using it for calling the base class constructor.

Comment: @user1386966: In this simple case, you *know* that `A` is the base class for `B` and that there is no other place `func1()` is going to be found.

Comment: thanks a lot! and another question - is it ok to locate first op3 and then super? order makes any difference?

Comment: @user1386966: You can order them any way you like. Calling `op3()` first, before invoking the base implementation means you reversed the operations, of course.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be : super(B, self).func1(self)? shouldn't be "self" inside func1?

Comment: @user1386966: No, because `super()` gives you a bound method. You don't have to pass in `self` when calling `B().func1()` either. `super()` can do this because it already has a reference to the instance; the second argument to `super()`.

Comment: but if for example in my class A I had : func1(self , x). so when using class B I would use super(A,self).func1(x) ?

Comment: @user1386966: Exactly, you got it in one. :-)